# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{s^2 + s + 1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve the following equation:
$$y'' + y' + y = 1 + e^{-t}$$

After applying the Laplace transform and using partial fractions I have terms of the form:

$$\frac{1}{s^2 + s + 1}$$
and $$\frac{s}{s^2+s+1}$$

which I don't know how to reverse transform. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give the initial conditions...a bit hard to check your solution

You have that
$$\frac{s}{s^2 + s + 1}=\frac{s}{(s^2 + s + 1/4 +3/4)}=\frac{s}{(s+1/2)^2 + 3/4}$$
$$\frac{s}{(s+1/2)^2 + 3/4}=\frac{s+1/2}{(s+1/2)^2 + 3/4}-\frac{1/2}{(s+1/2)^2 + 3/4}$$
And look at the sine and cosine function in the table...
$$\mathcal{L}({e^{at}\cos(\beta t)})=\frac {s-a}{(s-a)^2+\beta ^2 }$$
$$\mathcal{L}({e^{at}\sin(\beta t)})=\frac {\beta}{(s-a)^2+\beta ^2 }$$